# Having issues in my switch form jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm making a single page web application using switching form localstorage.

My problem is i have an animation picture using animation.css plugin in every form that takes seconds to finish. If i switch form fast enough that the animation on that form hasn't end yet it comes back to that the last form to end the animation and go the the last form i clicked.

I want to do is I can switch form even though the animation on that form hasn't end yet.

example html code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show-page" data-page="one">ONE</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show-page" data-page="two">TWO</a>

<div class="page one hide">
    <div class="row">
        <center> <h1>ONE</h1> </center>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page two hide">
    <div class="row">
        <center> <h1>TWO</h1> </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script code:

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem('pageToShow')) {
    var pageToShow = localStorage.getItem('pageToShow');
    $('.page').addClass('hide');
    $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
}
$('.show-page').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');

    $('.page').addClass('hide');
    $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
    }

});
```

Comment: Tip: Users like animated fx for a while, then it just turns to be a time consuming useless thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using animation.css class to `hide`, unhide the divs, considering this jQuery-only solution:

**Script:**

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem('pageToShow')) {
    var pageToShow = localStorage.getItem('pageToShow');
    $('.page').css("display", "none");
    $('.' + pageToShow).css("display", "block");
}
$('.show-page').click(function (e) {
   // e.preventDefault();
    var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');

    $('.page:not(.'+pageToShow+')').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $('.' + pageToShow).fadeIn(200);
    });

    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
    }

});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/778Lyazc/1/)